# Use sed command to apply a condition to check if a pattern has been matched

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I am searching for the string `::=BEGIN` and I want to apply a condition to check if the word has been found.

So, what I mean is something along these lines:

```
if (sed command does find a match for "::=BEGIN")
then i=1 
else i=0
```

Also, I want the 1 (for yes found) and 0 (not found) to be put into the variable "i".

Please help me out. Also provide a explanation to the solution! Thanks!

Comment: `grep '::= BEGIN' filename &> /dev/null` and then check `$?`.

Comment: @Nykakin grep has -q option, which does same job as `&> /dev/null`

Comment: I have a `sed` version for you =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` does that job well enough.

```
$ echo "::=BEGIN" > testfile1.txt

$ grep "::=BEGIN" -q testfile1.txt && echo "FOUND"
FOUND

$ grep "::=BEGIN" -q testfile1.txt && echo "FOUND" || echo "NOTFOUND"
FOUND

$ grep "whever" -q testfile1.txt && echo "FOUND" || echo "NOTFOUND"
NOTFOUND
```

What the code does is simply running a quiet search within subshell. `&&` , or logical AND operand, checks if the first command succeeded, and if it did, then it runs `echo "FOUND"` . `||` checks if that echo has been run, i.e., if we found anything. Second echo runs only if the first command failed.

Here's an `awk` version:

```
$ awk '{i="NOTFOUND";if($0~/::=BEGIN/) i="FOUNDIT";exit } END { print i}' testfile1.txt
FOUNDIT

$ awk '{i="NOTFOUND";if($0~/whatevs/) i="FOUNDIT";exit } END { print i}' testfile1.txt
NOTFOUND
```

Basic idea here is to set `i` to `NOTFOUND`, and if we find the string - change it to `FOUNDIT` . At the end after the first set of has finished processing file, we will print `i`, and it will tell us if we found something or not.

**Edit:** In the comment you mentioned that you want to place the result into a variable. Shell already provides a variable that reports exit status of the previous command, `$0`. Exit status 0 means success, everything else - fail. For instance,

```
$ grep "::=BEGIN" -q testfile1.txt  
$ echo $?
0
```

If you want to use exit status in a variable, you can do it like so : `MYVAR=$(echo $?)`. Remember , $? report exit status of previous command. So you must use this right after the grep command.

If you want to still use my earlier awk and grep one-liners, you can use same trick `MYVAR=$()` and place whatever command you want between the braces. The output will get assigned to variable `MYVAR`.

Comment: The user who downvoted the answer, please leave a comment explaining why you downvoted the answer

Comment: I don't know about the downvote (I don't have the rep points to do anything).  I lack much knowledge in GREP and SED(which is my main focus at this point of time). Any Idea on some good resources where i can do SED from? Already looked up Google most of the websites don't explain properly, they just use slashes here and their and stuff gets replaced  and exchanged blah blah blah.

Comment: @user2446359 yes, that's `sed's` syntax, which at times can turn into a gigantic mess. Besides it is a tool for editing stuff, not searching. `grep` is the right tool for that.  In your original question you did not mention putting the result into a variable. Please add that. I'll edit my answer in a second to address this requirement

Comment: @user2446359 edit is done, please see it

Comment: Thank you so much Serg! Made my day. I will use the echo $? and store it in a variable.

Comment: What is this? the OP asked for `sed` !

Answer (score 7):

With a GNU `sed` *(as is installed by default on any Ubuntu system)*:

```
{ sed -n '/::=BEGIN/Q 1'; i=$?; } <infile
```

Some facts about this answer:

1. `sed` `Q`uits input just as soon as the *very first match* is found anywhere in the file - which means it does not waste any more time continuing to read the infile.
2. `sed` *returns* in its *exit code* the numeric value *0* or *1* depending on whether it couldn't/could find the addressed regexp.
3. `$i` is set to `sed`'s return upon exit.
4. The `{` grouping `; }` is used to robustly handle any possible redirection error - `$i` is not set in the case the shell cannot open the file at all, thus avoiding false positives.

This probably shouldn't be preferred to `grep -q`, though, which can basically *also* do all of the above *(if in reverse)*, do it POSIXly, and usually faster.

The already given `grep -q` answer is very good, but, a little terser:

```
grep -q pattern ./infile; i=$((!$?))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in *::=BEGIN*) i=1 && break;;         
                               *) i=0
    esac
done <file.txt
```

This will search the file `file.txt` line by line and if a match of `::=BEGIN` found it  will set the variable `i=1` and exit. If no match is found, the variable will be set as `i=0`.

Answer (score 3):

My `sed` version

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' foo | sed '{/::=BEGIN/{s/.*/1/; b next}; s/.*/0/; :next}'
```

to store in a variable `i`:

```
i=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' foo | sed '{/::=BEGIN/{s/.*/1/; b next}; s/.*/0/; :next}')
```

---

Example:

```
$ echo "::=BEGIN" > foo
$ echo "::=BEGIN" >> foo
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' foo | sed '{/::=BEGIN/{s/.*/1/; b next}; s/.*/0/; :next}' 
1
$ echo "::=NOT_BEGIN" > foo
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' foo | sed '{/::=BEGIN/{s/.*/1/; b next}; s/.*/0/; :next}'
0
$ echo "::=BEGIN" >> foo
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' foo | sed '{/::=BEGIN/{s/.*/1/; b next}; s/.*/0/; :next}' 
1
```

---

Explanation:

- If `::=BEGIN` is found, print a `1` and jump to `next`
- If `::=BEGIN` is not found, print `0`

Comment: Good job bro ! I like it

Comment: @terdon corrected

Answer (score 1):

`sed` (Stream **EDitor**) is not the right tool for this kind of things: you can simply use a `bash` `if` statement to match your input against a regex:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#...
input="$(< inputfile)"
[[ "$input" =~ ::=BEGIN ]] && i=1 || i=0
#...
```

- `input="$(< inputfile)"`: assigns the content of `inputfile` to the variable `$input`
- `[[ "$input" =~ ::=BEGIN ]] && i=1 || i=0`: matches the regex `::=BEGIN` against the content of the variable `$input`; if there's a match it assigns `1` to `$i`, otherwise it assigns `0` to `$i`

Comment: see the comments under my answer